# macOS Full Bluetooth menu as default

Tags: macos, bluetooth

If I <kbd>Option</kbd>-Click the Bluetooth icon in macOS it shows extra options and information. What do I need to change to have these options shown with a normal click?

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting exposed directly to the user to make that change in the Bluetooth menu behavior, i.e. e.g., in System Preferences > Bluetooth > [] Show Bluetooth menu in menu bar, it only determines whether or not it's shown on the menu bar, not which menu is displayed by default or with modifier key(s) pressed upon being clicked. That is hard coded into `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Bluetooth.menu`.  Nor do I know of an indirect setting, e.g. using the `defaults` command, that can be used to achieve that which you've asked.

You'll just have to continue to option-click to get the secondary menu and shift-option-click to get the tertiary menu, or of course just click to get the default menu.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having two similar answers, there is no reason to flag similar answers as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

1. The **Default** for Bluetooth menu is just simple Click!

   [image]
2. Holding <kbd>Option</kbd> + Click (your Question) on BT will bring up Additional Information about BT. Again by Default setting.

   [image]
3. Holding <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click brings up Debugging menu.

   [image]